# Uso de FCKEditor en Genexus 16

Tags: genexus

**Buenas** estoy trabajando con un Web Component y he agregado a una variable Control Type "FCK Html Editor" necesitaría poder exportar a pdf lo ingresado y agregar Fecha y Hora al final del contenido que tenga escrito el editor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Deberías crearte un procedure que imprima un PDF, en el layout del mismo debes agregar una variable basada en HTML, y a la misma le asignas el contenido HTML que tienes en tu variable con FCKEditor.

Esto se explica en el [**SAC #32568**](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=46755;):

> Se implementó el formatear HTML en reportes PDF **Abstract** Formatea HTML y
> genera reportes que mantienen los formatos (style) de los campos (Ej.
> Bold, cursiva, etc.), de manera que se visualizan también en el
> reporte PDF. Aplica para los atributos del dominio con tipo de dato
> "HTML" y para cualquier atributo/variable del tipo String (Character,
> VarChar, LongVarChar), con la propiedad "Format" en HTML o RAWHTML.

La única limitación que tienes es el largo de la página, lo cual se solucionó a partir de GX16 U11 [**SAC #46755:**](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=46755;):

> Soportar contenido HTML que supere el largo de la página en reportes
> PDF **Abstract** En un reporte se incluye atributos o variables con
> contenido HTML, lo cual puede ser variable. Si ese contenido supera el
> tamaño de la pagina del reporte, aparecerá cortado. Se implementa una
> solución para evitar que aparezca cortado y continúa en la siguiente
> página.Descripción DetalladaEn reportes pdf se soportar el caso de que
> el largo del html que se pone en un campo exceda el largo de la
> página.
>
> Se implementó en Genexus V16 U11. e implica tener un printblock y una
> variable con el contenido Html con las propiedades width y height >=
> al largo y ancho máximo del reporte.
>
> Compatibilidad: Las propiedades Width y Height de una variable Raw
> Html en el Layout de un reporte son tomadas en cuenta para la
> implementación de esta funcionalidad. Esto significa , por ejemplo que
> podrían verse "cortados" reportes Pdf que tengan configurados valores
> pequeños en estas propiedades, que anteriormente no era tenida en
> cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

No se si ya pudiste resolverlo o no. Pero nunca esta de mas la info. Dentro de la documentación de ckeditor hay una [features](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/exporttopdf.html) que logra esto. Es pago, necesita licencia pero tiene prueba de 30 dias de prueba.

Cuando está habilitado, agrega un icono en la barra de herramientas que es un como un documento PDF. Cuando se hace clic en el botón, envía el contenido de tu variable  junto con los estilos que se utilizan para mostrarlo al servicio de conversión de HTML a PDF de CKEditor Cloud Services . A continuación, el servicio genera un documento PDF para descargar.

Por otra parte en GeneXus 17 ya tiene la funcionalidad el mismo control type. Te permite imprimir el resultado del control type lo que a su vez al imprimir podes guardarlo como PDF.

[image: Ese es el icono de imprimir que se pone automáticamente en el control type]

Y así podes guardarlo al darle imprimir. Lo "malo" es que tendrías que editar un poco el formato del PDF ya que contiene una plantilla del mismo ckeditor. Arriba coloca la hora y fecha junto a un texto. Y abajo de todo la url del objeto

[image: Este formato es por defecto.]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info